# Не создает миниатюры на категориях магазина WooCommerce

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, wp-plugin

Есть сайт на WordPress с плагином WooCommerce. Нужно, чтобы на категориях подгружались маленькие картинки, а грузятся оригинальные картинки с размером, заданным в настройках WooCommerce. Например:

```
<img width="156" height="156" src="//сайт/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/053751.jpg">
```

А хотелось бы, чтобы подгружались другие картинки, как на другом сайте, например:

```
<img width="156" height="156" src="https://сайт/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Veralinga-156x156.jpg">
```

На сайте, где картинка обрезана как положено, я использовал плагин `Regenerate Thumbnails`, но такие же действия на данном сайте ни к чему не привели.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в самопальных темах, которые не используют потенциал WooCommerce. WC выводит изображения с помощью `woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail()`, и html-код содержит srcset, что даёт правильные разрешения при любых размерах экрана.

Вместо того, чтобы писать свой код вывода категории WC, надо использовать шаблоны WC, копировать их в свою тему и там править. Вот тогда всё будет работать, как положено.

Comment: И что бы вы делали в моей ситуации?

Comment: Взял бы код вывода категории из WC, и подогнал бы его под требуемый дизайн. Ну или по крайней мере, выводил картинки с помощью указанной функции.